# How to link my simple jQuery Input with PHP script and Store data into a MYSQL DB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

What I'm trying to do is very simple.
Have a simple input, that allows me to input a name+link, add it to a  list and save it to a DB so it's saved.

In my HTML file I currently have:

```
<form id="form">
<input id="create-input" type="text" placeholder="To do">
<input id="create-link" type="text" placeholder="http://">
<button id="submit" type="button">Add Item</button>
</form>
```

In my JS file I have:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click', addListItem);
});

function addListItem() {

   // Grab Input Data
   var text = $('#create-input').val();
   var link = $('#create-link').val();

    // Creating To Do List
    $('#todo').append('<li>' +text+' - '+link+ ' <button class="delete">Edit</button> <button class="delete">Delete</button> <button class="delete">Bukkaked!</button></li>');
   $('#create-input').val('');
   $('#create-link').val('http://');

}
```

In my PHP file (connecting to DB) I have:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "bucketlist";
$username = "bucketuser";
$password = "125632";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "INSERT INTO bucketlist (item, link) VALUES ('Thom', 'www.google.com')";

// Check for Success

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
}

// Check for Fail

else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Now I know I need to somehow pass the vars (text and link) through to the PHP file:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bucketlist (item, link) VALUES ('Thom', 'www.google.com')";
```

But I have no idea how. 
Any tips?

Comment: You actually submit the form. http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: You could use ajax to send the form data... I would also change the event listener. I would have the event listener attached to the form it's self and listen for the submit event. `$('#form').on('submit', addListItem)` you will no doubt need to add `event.preventDefault();` to that too so the form doesn't submit which is a forms default action. I don't see the point posting a solution to this as I know many ajax example exists on stackoverflow so if you research you will find plenty of examples and detail of it works/how to use it.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with AJAX in the background, but learn to walk before you run.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JQuery you can pass values using php only

here is a change in your code:-

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="process.php">
<input id="create-input" name="item" type="text" placeholder="To do">
<input id="create-link" name="link" type="text" placeholder="http://">
<button id="submit" type="button">Add Item</button>
</form> 
<ul>
<?php include('conn.php');
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM bucketlist";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li>Item-'. $row["item"].' & Link-'. $row["link"].'</li>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<li>No List</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

conn.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "bucketlist";
$username = "bucketuser";
$password = "125632";    
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

process.php

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$item = $_POST['item'];
$item = $_POST['link'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO bucketlist (item, link) VALUES ($item,$link)";

// Check for Success

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     header('location:yourpage.php');
}

// Check for Fail

else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No doubt to keep the client on the same page rather than moving the client from one page to another? Also *"you can pass values using php only"* The changes you have made isn't making the form submit using php only. You have added the action attribute to a HTML element "The form" which isn't php... is it.

Comment: When I say to pass values using php only I wanted to say he/she don't need to use jquery. I typed it wrongly and he is providing half of the procedure he just don't know how to get those values so I changed his code only (seems he is new to php)

Comment: Then I would recommend you go into more detail about using the `<form>` element. Not only will this make your answer better but it will give the OP a better understanding of why the current source didn't work and why you made the changes you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to post the values of the item and link in your html form to your PHP script.
Something like :

```
var myItem = $('#create-input').html();
var myLink = $('#create-link').html();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://yoururl/api/post.php',
data: {item:myItem,link:myLink},
success: SuccessCall,
error : FailureCall,
cache:false,
async:true,
dataType: 'html'
}); 
function SuccessCall(data,status){
alert("response from server is "+data);
}
function FailureCall(data,status){
alert("Server connection error");
}
```

Use the PHP script posted by SYB to retrieve the values of item and link that were sent from your html form.